# How do bit manipulators work in mySQL (with this example)

Tags: mysql, sql, xor

This is an example for bit manipulation. I do not understand how `(id+1)^1-1` gives the shown output values. Please help.

Bit manipulation expression `(id+1)^1-1` can calculate the new id after switch.

```
SELECT id, (id+1)^1-1, student FROM seat;


| id | (id+1)^1-1 | student |

|----|------------|---------|

| 1  | 2          | Abbot   |

| 2  | 1          | Doris   |

| 3  | 4          | Emerson |

| 4  | 3          | Green   |

| 5  | 6          | Jeames  |
```

Answer (score 1):

[^](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-xor) is the bitwise XOR-operator. Bitwise `x XOR 1` switches the last bit of x (`1 xor 1 = 0`, `0 xor 1 = 1`), so it exchanges 0 and 1, 2 and 3 and so on.

So now you have a way to switch seats 0 and 1, 2 and 3, or, for this matter, seats 2 and 3, 3 and 4.

To use this to exchange 1 with 2, 3 and 4, you can first map `1, 2, 3, 4` to `2, 3, 4, 5`, apply the `XOR`, then map the result back to `1, 2, 3, 4`.

The function that maps `1, 2, 3, 4` to `2, 3, 4, 5` is `f(x) = x+1`. The reverse is `g(x) = x-1`.

So what you get is: `h(x) = g( xor1( f(x) ) )`. This is exactly your formula: apply `^1` to `id+1`, `(id+1)^1`, then undo the subsitution by applying `x-1` to this result, and you get `((id+1)^1)-1`.

Another substitution would have been to map `1, 2, 3, 4` to `0, 1, 2, 3` (with `f(x) = x-1` and `g(x) = x+1`), giving you the final formula `((id-1)^1)+1`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me present you how it is done:

first, `^` is XOR operation, so:

```
0^0 = 0
1^0 = 1
0^1 = 1
1^1 = 0
```

Note that `1 = 001` in binary form (I presented only relevant 3 bits to below explanation), so for example `2^1 = 010^001`:

```
    010
XOR 001
-------
    011 = 3

id |  binary id | id + 1 | binary id + 1 | binary (id + 1) ^ 1 | decimal (id + 1) ^ 1 | (id + 1) ^ 1 - 1
1  |  001       | 2      | 010           | 011                 | 3                    | 2
2  |  010       | 3      | 011           | 010                 | 2                    | 1
3  |  011       | 4      | 100           | 101                 | 5                    | 4
4  |  100       | 5      | 101           | 100                 | 4                    | 3
5  |  101       | 6      | 110           | 111                 | 7                    | 6
```